# Using Dropbox API for (subscription) content delivery

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I run a multi-gigabyte audio content subscription service. Right now all of our clients get download links via email for all of the content.

I had an idea of employing the Dropbox API after a "successful charge" webhook and giving (read-only) access to a shared Dropbox folder with all of the content. That way, the customer would stay in sync with all updates, changes etc...

The way I picture it, the user checks out and is immediately asked if he would like to add our company's folder to his/her Dropbox.

Does this seem feasible/practical?

Looking at the API, I only see an option to provide a download *link* but not an actual shared folder. Am I correct in this observation?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, the Dropbox API doesn't currently offer any API calls for managing shared folders. It only has [a way to get the read-only share links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares) like you mentioned.

However, if you'd be interested in potentially participating in a shared folder API beta in the future, please sign up [here](https://dropboxapi.wufoo.com/forms/dropbox-shared-folder-api-beta-contact-info/).

Answer (score 0):

@Greg's answer is correct, but I thought I'd mention a couple other options:

1. You could use the [Saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver/js) to let users save the files directly into their Dropbox. This wouldn't help you to push new content to them—they'd still have to visit your site to save the new files—but it would let you cut down on your bandwidth costs, since Dropbox would cache the files for you.
2. You could use a combination of [/copy_ref](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#copy_ref) and [/fileops/copy](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#fileops-copy) to copy the contents from a central Dropbox account into each user's Dropbox. This wouldn't use any of your bandwidth (once the file was in the central Dropbox account).

Please note, however, that free Dropbox accounts only start with 2GB of storage space. Since you mentioned "multi-gigabyte," you'll need to keep in mind whether your customers will actually have sufficient Dropbox space to store the files you want to share with them. (Even if you were able to use a shared folder, they would need to have enough space left to accept the shared folder invitation.)